# batch script to find missing sequence no

Tags: batch-file

I am new to batch script,

I am getting the source file in the format
ABC_CDEFG_HIJK_20120712105523_000001(both timestamp&sequnce no will be changing)
It can be single file or multiple file for every 30 mins.
I need to find out if there are any missing sequnece no from the list and send alert to the user.
Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean to find if the pattern of the file is not the expected?

Comment: For Eg:if I am getting these files  ABC_CDEFG_HIJK_20120712105523_000001, ABC_CDEFG_HIJK_20120712105828_000003.I need to send alert to the user that  file with sequence No.000002 is missing .

Answer (score 1):

assuming no extension,

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /l %%a in (1,999999,1) do (
set test1=000000%%a
set test2=!test1:~-6!
if not exist *!test2! goto loopexit
)

:loopexit
echo %test2% missing
```

if there is an extension, add it to the `if not exist` line, e.g. `if not exist *!test2!.txt goto loopexit`
It uses `test2` to test for the filename, as this is the one with all the extra zeros that you don't get from the loop `%a`

Comment: thanks for the reply,but the sequnece no. does not always start with 1,I need something like Assuming the files available in the directory are as follows 
File1.txt
File3.txt And the first suffix is 1 and the last suffix is 6 so generate all sequences (for i=1(First suffix);i<=6(Last suffix);i=i+1(increment number)) so Dummy.txt will contain all the below files              File1.txt
File2.txt
File3.txt 
Once you get this in unix you use diff command and achieve all the files missing in Actual.txt as below 
diff Actual.txt Dummy.txt | grep "^>" | cut -f2 -d">"  
Output will be  
File3.txt

Comment: i tired the following script,but i dont know how to go with the for loop,i dont know whether i can use variable for start,step,end

set /p var1=<SequenceNo.txt
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (SequenceNo.txt) do (
set var=%%a
)



FOR /L %i IN (%var1%,1,%var%) DO (
i=i+1

  ECHO Start of Loop
  ECHO %i >> dummy.txt
)

Comment: are you always looking at the last 6 chars of the filename, and will there be an extension?

Comment: i am using the following command to extract the sequence no from the filename and storing it in the text file    @ECHO OFF
REM Start of file
SET src_dir="C:\Users\radha.subbarayan\Desktop\Telus_Eagle_Proj\Voice\Input_Data\"
SET src_ext="*.dat"
SET sequence_file="SequenceNo.txt"
For /f "tokens=1-5 delims=_" %%a in ('dir %src_dir%%src_ext% /b') do echo   %%~ne >> temp.txt
sort temp.txt >> %src_dir%%sequence_file%
del temp.txt
::DONE    so there will be no extension,and yes always looking ar the last 6 character which is the sequence no.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

I've tested the following, and it works. *(My original code was not testing the very last base file name. This code has been fixed)*

This version loops through the files in alpha order and remembers the prior file name. When a change in the base name is detected it then looks for gaps in the prior base name sequences. The last base name is not tested in the loop so it must be tested after the loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "ext=.txt"
set "lastName="
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d *%ext% ^| findstr /irec:"_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%ext%"') do (
  set "name=%%~nF"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  if defined lastName if "!lastName:~0,-6!" neq "!name:~0,-6!" (
    for /f "delims=0" %%I in ("!lastName:~-6!") do (
      for /l %%N in (1 1 %%I) do (
        set "n=000000%%N"
        set "test=!lastName:~0,-6!!n:~-6!!ext!"
        if not exist "!test!" echo "!test!" is missing
      )
    )
  )
  endlocal
  set "lastName=%%~nF"
)
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
if defined lastname (
  for /f "delims=0" %%I in ("!lastName:~-6!") do (
    for /l %%N in (1 1 %%I) do (
      set "n=000000%%N"
      set "test=!lastName:~0,-6!!n:~-6!!ext!"
      if not exist "!test!" echo "!test!" is missing
    )
  )
)
```

**Option 2**

Here is another version (also tested and working) that uses less code. It loops through the files in alpha order and constructs a variable with the base name in the name and the sequence number as the value. Asterisks are used to delimit the sections of the name and value. A bit of trickery is used so that an `=` in the file name does not break the code. However, if multiple base names contain `=` in the name, then they must differentiate prior to the `=`, other wise only one of those names will be tested.

After the loop completes there is one variable for each base name that has the max sequence number in the value. A second loop iterates and parses the variables into base name and max sequence number, and then looks for gaps in the sequence number.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "ext=.txt"
for /f "delims==" %%A in ('2^>nul set file*') do set "%%A="
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d *%ext% ^| findstr /irec:"_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%ext%"') do (
  set "name=%%~nF"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for /f "delims=" %%A in ("file*!name:~0,-6!*=*!name:~-6!") do (
    endlocal
    set %%A
  )
)
for /f "tokens=2,4 delims=*" %%A in ('set file*') do (
  set "name=%%A"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for /l %%N in (1 1 %%B) do (
    set "n=000000%%N"
    set "test=!name!!n:~-6!!ext!"
    if not exist "!test!" echo "!test!" is missing
  )
  endlocal
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I tried the above script,My output file look like this " is missing" " is missing" " is missing"

Comment: @user1521157 - I got different results when I tested, but there was a bug. I've fixed the code and provided a 2nd solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
ls -1|awk -F "_" '{print $4}'|cut -d. -f1 >seq.txt

awk 'p && p != $1 { for( i = p; i < $1; i++ ) print i; } {p = $1 + 1 }'  seq.txt
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer ?

Comment: This is a solution for **bash** not **batch**! Note the difference!