# dos batch file find missing sequential filenames

Tags: batch-file

Here is the situation, I have directories that have 10,000 files in each directory named like this:

FileName.XX0000.csv

FileName.XX9999.csv

The Size of the filename itself can change ie:

FileName.XXX0000.csv

FileName.XXX9999.csv

FileName.XXXX0000.csv

FileName.XXXX9999.csv

Where the X's are yet another parent number, but these ones should be ignored anyway.

Regardless though all directories are supposed to have exactly 10,000 files no more and no less. The trouble is some are missing and I need to know which ones are missing.

I tried the scripts in this post:
[batch script to find missing sequence no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454701/batch-script-to-find-missing-sequence-no)

I even messed around with the string sequnce for several hours to no avail. Neither of these options works very well the 2nd script comes close but ends up in an endless loop, or spits out files that do exist.

I need to come up with a solution that will easily tell me which numbers or file names are missing. In my Dream world I would love a script where I can place it inside a parent directory and it would crawl through all the sub directories and print a single file of the missing ones.

It would be nice to not have to tell the script what the beginning part of the file name is, since in theory it should only be looking to see if the last four numbers are in existance from 0000-9999.

Since this is my first post I am hoping I doing this correctly by creating a new topic, I was going to ADD my question to the previous topic until I saw the "But avoid …" in the post box!

Answer (score 6):

Let's see if you can write some code.

- `FOR /L` can count from 0 to 9999
- `IF NOT EXIST` can test if a file is missing, and it supports wild cards.
- `>` and `>>` can redirect output to a file

For your dream world:

- `FOR /D /R %%F IN (.)` will iterate an entire folder hierarchy

**Edit**

You probably will need to left pad a number with zeros so that the width is always 4 digits. Since this will probably be within a loop, you will want to use delayed expansion. Assume %%N is a FOR variable that contains a number.

```
set num=000%%N
set num=!num:~-4!
```

Comment: the style of apprenticeship seems awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that will find all the missing files in a continuous sequence:

```
@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set max=1208
set cnt=0

for /L %%f in (0,1,%max%) do (
    set "num=00000%%f"    
    set "num=!num:~-4!"
    if not exist "img!num!.png" (
        echo img!num!.png
        set /A "cnt=!cnt!+1"
    )
) 
echo NUMBER MISSING: !cnt!

endlocal
```

Notice inside the loop you need to use `!x!` instead of `%x%` to get a local delayed variable.

Comment: In the `set` statements prior to the loop, there can't be a space before or after the equal sign.  It should be: `set max=1208` and `set cnt=0`.